# Bootstrap: Responsive nav-menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my page i have a navbar-menu. I re-size my page but menu doesn't show correctly. Button, home and image aren't set vertically, and in some size they are not in a line horizontally.

This is my code: [`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/J3mNF/4/)

How can i fix my problem?

Comment: you have favourites or favorites spelled incorrectly btw

Comment: میتونید ایتم ها رو توی `ul/li` قرار بدید.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Width col navbar-header > from col-xs-4 to col-xs-12. Check other width settings from the grid system

```
div class="navbar-header col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"
```

Position A elements with left float

```
.nav-menu .navbar-header a{
   float: left;
}
```

Position menu toggle with left float

```
.navbar-toggle {
   float: left;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that is happening because your nav header hasn't got `width` set

```
.navbar-header {
    width:100%;
}
```

and it should be fine now! 
 <kbd>[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J3mNF/2/)</kbd>

**EDIT**

after removing `col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4` from `<div class="navbar-header">`  [still looks fine](http://jsfiddle.net/J3mNF/3/)